# How to import Timestamp from a CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to Import a CSV file with a column called timestamp to MySQl to a column with the structure timestamp but all i get are NULLS in the columns is there a way that i can import the timestamp as the structure to my new table.

```
Transaction Timestamp,Batch Ref No,Transaction Type,Group Transaction No,Receipt No,Transaction No,Transaction Amount,Actual Cost,CErr,Resource Units,Resource Units Error,Operator Name,Account Number,Debt Reference No,Meter Serial No,Token,Comment,Station,Database Name,Resource,Tax Item Name,Fixed Charge Item Category,Debt Category,Utility Name,Vend Reason
6/1/2012 0:09,SH/EVG4/1108,Tax Transaction,EVG400021324,,EVG400050154,2761.54,0,0,0,0,EFULUSI,AGR1784471690,,1318958574,,,STN EVG4_CLIENT,TANOLS01,Electricity,VAT + EWURA + REA,,,Tanesco,
6/1/2012 0:09,SH/EVG4/1108,Fixed Cost Transaction,EVG400021324,,EVG400050155,3841,0,0,0,0,EFULUSI,AGR1784471690,,1318958574,,,STN EVG4_CLIENT,TANOLS01,Electricity,,Basic Support Charge,,Tanesco,
6/1/2012 0:09,SH/EVG4/1108,Tax Transaction,EVG400021324,,EVG400050156,845.02,0,0,0,0,EFULUSI,AGR1784471690,,1318958574,,,STN EVG4_CLIENT,TANOLS01,Electricity,VAT + EWURA + REA,Basic Support Charge,,Tanesco,
```

that is a sample of the CSV file that am trying to import everything else imports well except the timestamp, my structure is so that the timestamp structure is set to "timestamp"

Comment: Show us what you're trying to do... What does the CSV data look like? What is your table structure?

Comment: How do you import the file - by commandline, phpmyadmin, custom php-script? I myself tested it with phpmyadmin and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get NULL values probably because MySQL cannot determine automatically that first column in you CSV is a timestamp.
You could try to change table structure so first column becomes a VARCHAR, then import data, then transform dates using mysql date functions (change date to mysql standard format `'Y-M-D H:i:s'`), then convert back this column to timestamp.

Alternatively, you could use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to insert CSV data directly, but for first column use `SET` directive in `LOAD DATA INFILE` to change first column data to MySQL standard format. Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE youfile.csv 
  INTO TABLE yourtable
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
  LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
  (@var1, col_name_2, ...) SET col_name_1 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%m/%d/%Y %k:%i');
```

This converts date to MySQL format while importing data.